# Compiling OpenCV on Windows Link1181 Error, python3.obj instead of python3.lib

Tags: python, opencv, cmake

I am trying to compile OpenCV Python library with CUDA / CuDNN support, mainly using the guide available [here](https://learnopencv.com/how-to-use-opencv-dnn-module-with-nvidia-gpu-on-windows/) and I have troubles with Step 5: building OpenCV.

I installed:

- Visual Studio 2022 with the Windows 10 SDK and Desktop Development Kit.
- CMake (v3.22.1)
- CuDNN (v8.3)
- CUDA (v11.6)

After cloning the OpenCV repo and checking version 4.5.5, I created an Anaconda virtual environment named `opencv_env` and then launched:

```
set cwd=%cd%
set envName=opencv_env
set opencv-version=4.5.5

conda activate %envName%
set CONDA_PREFIX=%CONDA_PREFIX:\=/%

cd %cwd%

mkdir OpenCV-%opencv-version%
cd opencv
mkdir build
cd build

cmake ^
-G "Visual Studio 17 2022" ^
-T host=x64 ^
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE ^
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=%cwd%/OpenCV-%opencv-version% ^
-DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=%cwd%/opencv_contrib/modules ^
-DINSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=OFF ^
-DINSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF ^
-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=%CONDA_PREFIX%/python3 ^
-DPYTHON3_LIBRARY=%CONDA_PREFIX%/libs/python3.lib ^
-DWITH_CUDA=ON ^
-DWITH_CUDNN=ON ^
-DCUDNN_INCLUDE_DIR=C:\NVIDIA\CUDNN\v8.3\include ^
-DCUDNN_LIBRARY=C:\NVIDIA\CUDNN\v8.3\lib\x64\cudnn.lib ^
-DCUDNN_VERSION='8.3' ^
-DOPENCV_DNN_CUDA=ON ^
-DWITH_CUBLAS=ON ^
-DWITH_NGRAPH=ON ^
..
```

Which basically configures CMake for compilation, and I got the following:

```
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19042.
-- Detected processor: AMD64
-- libjpeg-turbo: VERSION = 2.1.2, BUILD = opencv-4.5.5-libjpeg-turbo
-- Could NOT find OpenJPEG (minimal suitable version: 2.0, recommended version >= 2.3.1). OpenJPEG will be built from sources
-- OpenJPEG: VERSION = 2.4.0, BUILD = opencv-4.5.5-openjp2-2.4.0
-- OpenJPEG libraries will be built from sources: libopenjp2 (version "2.4.0")
-- found Intel IPP (ICV version): 2020.0.0 [2020.0.0 Gold]
-- at: C:/Users/XXX/opencv/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/icv
-- found Intel IPP Integration Wrappers sources: 2020.0.0
-- at: C:/Users/XXX/opencv/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/iw
-- CUDA detected: 11.6
-- CUDA: Using CUDA_ARCH_BIN=3.5;3.7;5.0;5.2;6.0;6.1;7.0;7.5;8.0;8.6
-- CUDA NVCC target flags: -gencode;arch=compute_35,code=sm_35;-gencode;arch=compute_37,code=sm_37;-gencode;arch=compute_50,code=sm_50;-gencode;arch=compute_52,code=sm_52;-gencode;arch=compute_60,code=sm_60;-gencode;arch=compute_61,code=sm_61;-gencode;arch=compute_70,code=sm_70;-gencode;arch=compute_75,code=sm_75;-gencode;arch=compute_80,code=sm_80;-gencode;arch=compute_86,code=sm_86;-D_FORCE_INLINES
-- CUDA: MSVS generator is detected. Disabling CMake re-run checks (CMAKE_SUPPRESS_REGENERATION=ON). You need to run CMake XXXally if updates are required.
-- Could not find OpenBLAS include. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
-- Could not find OpenBLAS lib. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
-- Could NOT find BLAS (missing: BLAS_LIBRARIES)
-- Could NOT find LAPACK (missing: LAPACK_LIBRARIES)
    Reason given by package: LAPACK could not be found because dependency BLAS could not be found.

-- Could NOT find JNI (missing: JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH)
-- VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file
-- Module opencv_alphamat disabled because the following dependencies are not found: Eigen
-- freetype2:   NO
-- harfbuzz:    NO
-- Julia not found. Not compiling Julia Bindings.
-- Module opencv_ovis disabled because OGRE3D was not found
-- No preference for use of exported gflags CMake configuration set, and no hints for include/library directories provided. Defaulting to preferring an installed/exported gflags CMake configuration if available.
-- Failed to find installed gflags CMake configuration, searching for gflags build directories exported with CMake.
-- Failed to find gflags - Failed to find an installed/exported CMake configuration for gflags, will perform search for installed gflags components.
-- Failed to find gflags - Could not find gflags include directory, set GFLAGS_INCLUDE_DIR to directory containing gflags/gflags.h
-- Failed to find glog - Could not find glog include directory, set GLOG_INCLUDE_DIR to directory containing glog/logging.h
-- Module opencv_sfm disabled because the following dependencies are not found: Eigen Glog/Gflags
-- Tesseract:   NO
-- Allocator metrics storage type: 'long long'
-- Registering hook 'INIT_MODULE_SOURCES_opencv_dnn': C:/Users/XXX/opencv/modules/dnn/cmake/hooks/INIT_MODULE_SOURCES_opencv_dnn.cmake
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/dnn/layers/layers_common.rvv.cpp
-- imgcodecs: OpenEXR codec is disabled in runtime. Details: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/21326
-- highgui: using builtin backend: WIN32UI
-- rgbd: Eigen support is disabled. Eigen is Required for Posegraph optimization
-- Building with NVIDIA Optical Flow API 2.0
-- Found 'misc' Python modules from C:/Users/XXX/opencv/modules/python/package/extra_modules
-- Found 'mat_wrapper;utils' Python modules from C:/Users/XXX/opencv/modules/core/misc/python/package
-- Found 'gapi' Python modules from C:/Users/XXX/opencv/modules/gapi/misc/python/package
-- Found 'misc' Python modules from C:/Users/XXX/opencv/modules/python/package/extra_modules
-- Found 'mat_wrapper;utils' Python modules from C:/Users/XXX/opencv/modules/core/misc/python/package
-- Found 'gapi' Python modules from C:/Users/XXX/opencv/modules/gapi/misc/python/package
CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVGenSetupVars.cmake:54 (message):
  CONFIGURATION IS NOT SUPPORTED: validate setupvars script in install
  directory
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:1035 (include)


--
-- General configuration for OpenCV 4.5.5 =====================================
--   Version control:               4.5.5
--
--   Extra modules:
--     Location (extra):            C:/Users/XXX/opencv_contrib/modules
--     Version control (extra):     4.5.5
--
--   Platform:
--     Timestamp:                   2022-01-17T19:05:56Z
--     Host:                        Windows 10.0.19042 AMD64
--     CMake:                       3.22.1
--     CMake generator:             Visual Studio 17 2022
--     CMake build tool:            C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/amd64/MSBuild.exe
--     MSVC:                        1930
--     Configuration:               Debug Release
--
--   CPU/HW features:
--     Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
--       requested:                 SSE3
--     Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
--       requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
--       SSE4_1 (18 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
--       SSE4_2 (2 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
--       FP16 (1 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
--       AVX (5 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
--       AVX2 (33 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
--       AVX512_SKX (8 files):      + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_COMMON AVX512_SKX
--
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ standard:                11
--     C++ Compiler:                C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.30.30705/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe  (ver 19.30.30709.0)
--     C++ flags (Release):         /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /MP  /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /MP  /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
--     C Compiler:                  C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.30.30705/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
--     C flags (Release):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /MP   /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /MP /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
--     Linker flags (Release):      /machine:x64  /INCREMENTAL:NO
--     Linker flags (Debug):        /machine:x64  /debug /INCREMENTAL
--     ccache:                      NO
--     Precompiled headers:         YES
--     Extra dependencies:          cudart_static.lib nppc.lib nppial.lib nppicc.lib nppidei.lib nppif.lib nppig.lib nppim.lib nppist.lib nppisu.lib nppitc.lib npps.lib cublas.lib cudnn.lib cufft.lib -LIBPATH:C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.6/lib/x64 -LIBPATH:C:/NVIDIA/CUDNN/v8.3/lib/x64
--     3rdparty dependencies:
--
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 aruco barcode bgsegm bioinspired calib3d ccalib core cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev datasets dnn dnn_objdetect dnn_superres dpm face features2d flann fuzzy gapi hfs highgui img_hash imgcodecs imgproc intensity_transform line_descriptor mcc ml objdetect optflow phase_unwrapping photo plot python3 quality rapid reg rgbd saliency shape stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching text tracking ts video videoio videostab wechat_qrcode xfeatures2d ximgproc xobjdetect xphoto
--     Disabled:                    world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 alphamat cvv freetype hdf java julia matlab ovis python2 sfm viz
--     Applications:                tests perf_tests apps
--     Documentation:               NO
--     Non-free algorithms:         NO
--
--   Windows RT support:            NO
--
--   GUI:                           WIN32UI
--     Win32 UI:                    YES
--     VTK support:                 NO
--
--   Media I/O:
--     ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.11)
--     JPEG:                        build-libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.1.2-62)
--     WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
--     PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.37)
--     TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.2.0)
--     JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 2.4.0)
--     OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
--     HDR:                         YES
--     SUNRASTER:                   YES
--     PXM:                         YES
--     PFM:                         YES
--
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394:                      NO
--     FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
--       avcodec:                   YES (58.134.100)
--       avformat:                  YES (58.76.100)
--       avutil:                    YES (56.70.100)
--       swscale:                   YES (5.9.100)
--       avresample:                YES (4.0.0)
--     GStreamer:                   NO
--     DirectShow:                  YES
--     Media Foundation:            YES
--       DXVA:                      YES
--
--   Parallel framework:            Concurrency
--
--   Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)
--
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Intel IPP:                   2020.0.0 Gold [2020.0.0]
--            at:                   C:/Users/XXX/opencv/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/icv
--     Intel IPP IW:                sources (2020.0.0)
--               at:                C:/Users/XXX/opencv/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/iw
--     Lapack:                      NO
--     nGraph:                      NO
--     Eigen:                       NO
--     Custom HAL:                  NO
--     Protobuf:                    build (3.19.1)
--
--   NVIDIA CUDA:                   YES (ver 11.6, CUFFT CUBLAS)
--     NVIDIA GPU arch:             35 37 50 52 60 61 70 75 80 86
--     NVIDIA PTX archs:
--
--   cuDNN:                         YES (ver 8.3)
--
--   OpenCL:                        YES (NVD3D11)
--     Include path:                C:/Users/XXX/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Link libraries:              Dynamic load
--
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 C:/Users/XXX/.conda/envs/opencv_env/python.exe (ver 3.9.7)
--     Libraries:                   C:/Users/XXX/.conda/envs/opencv_env/libs/python3 (ver 3.9.7)
--     numpy:                       C:/Users/XXX/.conda/envs/opencv_env/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.22.1)
--     install path:                C:/Users/XXX/.conda/envs/opencv_env/Lib/site-packages/cv2/python-3.9
--
--   Python (for build):            C:/Users/XXX/.conda/envs/opencv_env/python.exe
--
--   Java:
--     ant:                         NO
--     JNI:                         NO
--     Java wrappers:               NO
--     Java tests:                  NO
--
--   Install to:                    C:/Users/XXX/OpenCV-4.5.5
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/XXX/opencv/build
```

Which is fine, I guess. But when building with:

```
cmake --build . --config Release --target INSTALL
```

I got the following:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 17.0.0+c9eb9dd64 pour .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits réservés.

  libopenjp2.vcxproj -> C:\Users\XXX\opencv\build\3rdparty\lib\Release\libopenjp2.lib
  [LOTS OF TEXT CUT HERE, compiling stuff to lib, dll and exe files]
  opencv_waldboost_detector.vcxproj -> C:\Users\XXX\opencv\build\bin\Release\opencv_waldboost_detector.exe
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: impossible d'ouvrir le fichier en entrée 'C:\Users\XXX\.conda\envs\opencv_env\libs\python3.obj' [C:\Users\XXX\opencv\build\modules\python3\opencv_python3.vcxproj]
```

Everything goes fine untill a **LNK1181 fatal error**. From what I understand, the error comes from the impossibility to open `C:\Users\XXX\.conda\envs\opencv_env\libs\python3.obj` which indeed does not exist. The file present at this location is **python3.lib** and not **python3.obj**.

I tried to add `.lib` at the end of the `PYTHON3_LIBRARY` CMake line:

`-DPYTHON3_LIBRARY=%CONDA_PREFIX%/libs/python3.lib`

But the linker still searches a `.obj` file. Is there a way to force the linker to take the `.lib` file instead? (Assuming this is the real cause for the error I mentioned) And if so, how?

Comment: any luck with this? did you manage to solve it, i have been stuck with this issue for the past 19 days...

Answer (score 0):

I did the following to get past this (I tested with my OpenCV-4.6.0 install and confirmed it worked fine):

1. copy `python3.lib` to `python3.obj` in the same directory
2. copied `python3.lib` and `python310.lib` into `../opencv/build/modules/python3`
3. restart the cmake build (I did *not* clean/uninstall first)